# logic error trying to find average of 2d array

Tags: java

this always outputs 1 and i dont know why,  im trying to make a method that takes the average of the elements of a 2d array.  this is part of a class and im calling it from a main class.

```
public static double Ave(Array_two a) {
        int average = 0;
        int total = a.rows * a.cols;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                average = a.values[i][j] / total;
            }
        }
        return average;
```

Comment: `j < cols;` I guess this should be `j < a.cols`

Comment: Also, integer division will yield integer results.

Comment: Also, that's not how you calculate an average. You sum all the numbers and just at the end you return it divided by the number of elements.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca you should gather all that in an answer

Comment: @JackFlamp done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.

First, I guess `j < cols` in the inner loop should be `j < a.cols`.

Second, and most important, this is not how you calculate the average of a set of numbers.

You should first sum them, then divide the total by the number of samples. Like this, for example

```
public static double Ave(Array_two a) {
    double sum = 0; // you want to return a double
    double total = a.rows * a.cols;
    if (total == 0) return 0; // watch out for possible division by 0
    for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.cols; j++) {
            sum += a.values[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum / total;
}
```

Comment: well, now you gave him a complete solution to a school assignment. but whatever. hopefully he will try to understand it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get average like this:

```
public static double Ave(Array_two a) {
    int count = a.rows * a.cols;

    if (count == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.cols; j++) {
            total += a.values[i][j];
        }
    }

    return total / count;
}
```

Comment: if count==0 return 0 what is this

Comment: Average of -1 and 1 is 0 is understandable ,but average of nothing is also zero is ......

Comment: @javafan if you don't check for `count == 0` it will bite you at the end when you do `total / count`. Division by zero is no fun :)

Comment: Thats fine but returning the average of nothing as 0 is also a kind of biting

Comment: In that case we could throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

```
    Double average = Arrays
            .stream(new double[][]{{1.2, 3.4}, {1.2, 3.4}})
            .mapToDouble(
                    row -> Arrays.stream(row).average().getAsDouble()
            )
            .average()
            .getAsDouble();
```

If use java 8

Answer (score 0):

As Federico klez Culloca says in the comments, this isn't quite the correct code to calculate an average. You need to sum all the values in your for loops and then divide by the total number of values afterwards. He is also correct about the fact that the average need to be a double (a decimal) otherwise the result will be an int (a whole number). You should try something like:

```
public static double Ave(Array_two a) {
    double average = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int total = a.rows * a.cols;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.cols; j++) {
            sum += a.values[i][j];
        }
    }
    average = sum / total;
    return average;
}
```

Where `sum +=  a.values[i][j];` means `sum = sum + a.values[i][j];`
Hope this helps! Feel free to comment if you need more clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Federicoklez  already commented here are the problem with your code..

1) Instead of j < cols there should be j < a.cols

2) Integer divided by integer yiels an integer
    i.e  **5/2=2 not 2.5**

3) For example ,If you want to calculate average of **{1,5,2,3}**
   it is calculated as **{1+5+2+3}/4**  ,**i.e. sum of numbers dived by number     of items**  but what you calculated is *1/4+5/4+2/4+3/4*;

Now implementing all this in your program will give something like this.

```
   public static double Ave(Array_two a) {

        int total = a.rows * a.cols;
        double sum=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                sum +=a.values[i][j];
            }
        }
        return sum/total;
  }
```